# How to detect blank images from set of scanned documents using java?

Tags: java, awt, scanning

I am using Asprise Scanning and Image Capture SDK for scanning and atalasoft jolt image for cleaning image in my application.I want to group scanned documents.We are using blank paper for separating groups.How to detect these blank pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is "cleaned", i. e. not grey in some regions, you can specify a threshold value for arithmetic mean of all points; using Graphics2D in Java for example.

Comment: I already do it and got the expected result.anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: So do you still have a problem? If so, what is it?